# How to set screen resolution in IOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I build and run my old iPad app for IOS 7.
The screen resolution is twice as it was.

I don't want to re write  the code to position the controls

There is no storyboard. Everything is in code

Can I have the same resolution in IOS 7 as it was before?

Comment: Are you seeing problems?  The resolution is 2x, but positioning shouldn't change.

Comment: I don't think there should be any problems.

Comment: Are you drawing your own custom controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen coordinates are still the same, the coordinates are in floating point.

The screen resolution is 2048 x 1536 but if you get the CGRect frame for the entire screen it is is still  1024x768, as GGRect is floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem. You shouldn't have any issue with de position of all element because there is no change in the coordinate system.

The thing you need to do is design image with retina size. For exemple if you had an image 2x2 you need the same image with the same proportion but in 4x4.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be running an iPhone app on the iPad. On the new iPads the iPhone Apps run in 2x mode automatically on iOS 7 using the retina assets.